# Changing and adding to lists within dictionaries in python2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to create an ATM simulator

I have this part of my code which will be saved to a file.

```
bank = {'bob':[1122,0],'fred':[2211,0]}
```

The key is the users name, then the values are - Pin and balance.

I want to print and be able to change just the balances of the dictionary.

I have tried things like

```
values =bank.values()
print values[0]
```

But that prints both pin and balance.

Comment: `bank[name][1]`? You should really have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: **NEVER**, ever, store confidential information like PIN in plain text.

Comment: its not real. its a task I have set for students at my school

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary value is nested ... You need to go one level deeper

```
>>> bank = {'bob':[1122,0],'fred':[2211,0]}
>>> values =bank.values()
>>> print values[0]
[1122, 0]
>>> print values[0][1]
0
```

As you can see `values[0][1]` can be used to access the balance inside the list in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all the balances, try this:

```
for value in bank:
    print value[1]
```

But it would be better to change your data structure to:

```
{'bob' : {'pin': 1122, 'balance': 0},
 'fred' : {'pin': 2211, 'balance': 0}}
```

and access to values as:

```
for account in bank:
    print account['balance']
```

or

```
bank['bob']['balance']
```